# Why does passing an NSString object to the "format" parameter of XCTAssertTrue cause a build error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xctest

In attempting to use XCTest to test my application, I get a build error when doing the following:

```c
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface MyTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation MyTests

- (void)testExample
{
    NSString *str = @"foo";
    XCTAssertTrue(YES, str); // Parse issue: Expected ')'
}

@end
```

but I **do not** get a build error if I do this:

```c
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface MyTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation MyTests

- (void)testExample
{
    XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"foo"); // this is just fine...
}

@end
```

The build error that I get is:

```
Parse issue: Expected ')'
```

and it puts an arrow under the "s" in "str".

I discovered that I can remedy this by changing

```
XCTAssertTrue(YES, str)
```

to

```
XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"%@", str)
```

but I just cannot figure out why that makes a difference. Can somebody please explain why this is so?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `XCT...` macros are written to accept format strings — the strings themselves are optional (so that writing `XCTAssertTrue(YES)` is valid), but they must be constant strings. You cannot pass objects into the macro without having a format string, which is why `XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"%@", str)` works, but, say, `XCTAssertTrue(YES, str)` or `XCTAssertTrue(NO, nil)` wouldn't.

Comment: But in the case of using the string literal, `XCTAssertTrue(YES,@"foo")`, isn't that really an `NSString *` object anyways?

Comment: The string literal `@"foo"` does get converted into an `NSString *` object at runtime, but at compile time, string literals have additional meaning. The `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` attribute lets the compiler know a function accepts a `printf`-style string literal as a format string, and additional objects as inputs to that; if you follow the implementations of the macros all the way down, you'll eventually find the `_XCTFailureHandler` function, which is marked with `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(6,7)`. If you try to call that function with a non-string-literal object, you'll get a warning or an error.

Comment: Macro error reporting can be a little strange — because the preprocessor essentially copies and pastes the contents of macros into your code, a failure (such as the one above) can propagate upward and give you a somewhat irrelevant error message, like you see there.

Answer (score 4):

Deep inside the implementation, the code does this:

```
    @"" format
```

If `format` is a constant string literal, the compiler concatenates the strings. If `format` is anything else, you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Passing predefined text into the assertion is sometimes desirable so:

```
XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"foo"); // this is just fine...
```

As is this

```
#define FOO @"foo"
XCTAssertTrue(YES, FOO); // this is just fine too...
```

So I do stuff like:

```
#define DBUEqualityTestFailed @"Equality test failed"

// test
DBNumber *n1 = [@((int)1) dbNumberFromIntValue];

XCTAssertTrue(*(int *)[n1 valuePointer] == 1, DBUEqualityTestFailed);
XCTAssertTrue([n1 valuePointer] == [n1 valuePointer], DBUEqualityTestFailed);
XCTAssertTrue(*(int *)[n1 valuePointer] == *(int *)[n1 valuePointer], DBUEqualityTestFailed);
```